# In SoftLayer how can i use the API to get a detailed list of all the times a monitoring alarm was triggered?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I use this REST request I only get back the first time the alarm fired. `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/{GUEST_ID}/MonitoringActiveAlarms.json with body: {"parameters":["2017-10-31T18:14:00-04:00","2017-11-08T12:54:34-05:00"]}`

However in the console UI, I see the alarm with a timestamp similar to the one I get back, but when i drill down into it, I can see all the subsequent times the monitoring alarm reported being beyond the threshold. How can I acquire this info using an API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you require to do is to use another method, but previously you need to save the "alarmId" value obtained in your REST request posted above, this alarmId property will let you obtain the subsequent alarms, this is obtained trough SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getAlarmHistory.

To do what you require just as in the portal UI, use the following REST request:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/{GUEST_ID}/getAlarmHistory 
method POST
 {"parameters":[
                "2000-01-01T18:14:00-04:00", 
                 "2017-11-08T12:54:34-05:00",  
                 "UH37931229-00012"
                ]
  }
```